# mootools formcheck 2 of 4 criteria

Tags: javascript, passwords, mootools

I use http://mootools.net as JS form validation script. I want to check if the password the user chose contains two of these four criteria:

```
minimum 1 digit
minimum 1 small letter
minimum 1 capital letter
minimum 1 special character (!@#$%^*-_+=.)
```

And at least between 6 and 50 digits.

It works finde with this extension:

```
uppercase: /(?=^.{6,50}$)((?=.*\d)|([!,%,&,@,#,$,^,*,?,_,~]))(?![.\n])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).*$/
```

This checks if the users password conform to all four criteria. Now I want to change the script in this way, that the password is accepted if it just conform to two aof this. Any idea how to change the script?

Answer (score 1):

you can use something like this plugin I wrote years ago:

https://github.com/DimitarChristoff/StrongPass

it allows you to split your checks and assign a relative score and an overall passing score, the idea being that not all checks are equally strong. additionally, score is upped for longer lengths.

```
checks: [
    /* alphaLower */ {
        re: /[a-z]/,
        score: 1
    },
    /* alphaUpper */ {
        re: /[A-Z]/,
        score: 5
    },
    /* mixture of upper and lowercase */ {
        re: /([a-z].*[A-Z])|([A-Z].*[a-z])/,
        score: 2
    },
    /* threeNumbers */ {
        re: /(.*[0-9].*[0-9].*[0-9])/,
        score: 7
    },
    /* special chars */ {
        re: /.[!@#$%^&*?_~]/,
        score: 5
    },
    /* multiple special chars */ {
        re: /(.*[!@#$%^&*?_~].*[!@#$%^&*?_~])/,
        score: 7
    },
    /* all together now, does it look nice? */ {
        re: /([a-zA-Z0-9].*[!@#$%^&*?_~])|([!@#$%^&*?_~].*[a-zA-Z0-9])/,
        score: 3
    },
    /* password of a single char sucks */ {
        re: /(.)\1+$/,
        score: 2
    }
],
```

so you can break down your regex and add them here or look at the source and get some ideas.